# How to secure post/put/patch payload within Django views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've been using django serializers for a while now, And it seems like any time I send a payload using put/post/patch, `serializers.is_valid()` only checks if the payload data attributes types are correct, required ones are present and does not check if there are surplus data in the payload not defined in `models.py`

Let's say that I have `models.py :`

```py
    class Task(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='default_task_name')
        description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, default='')
        complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        canceled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('id', 'date')
```

In my `serializers.py` i have the following :

```py
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Task


    class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Task
            fields = '__all__'
```

In my `views.py`I have the following :

```py
    class TaskDetails(APIView):
        def get_object(self, pk):
            try:
                return Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except Task.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
        def put(self, request, pk):
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = TaskSerializer(self.get_object(pk), data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
```

using `cURL` :

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"task_1", "description":"learning rest", "task_force":"undefined "}' "my_api_uri"
```

I except to get error like this :

`'errors': {'task_force': ['undefined attribute task_force'], 'status_code': '422'}`

since the payload contains task_force that is not define inside models.py or serializers.py

But I'm getting a response with no errors:

`{data={"title":"task_1", "description":"learning rest", "task_force":"undefined "}, "status_code": '201'}`
`

What is a work around here to make that check with the serializer ?

Comment: TaskSerializer will be listening at structure data that contains all the fields define at models or serializer. whatever extra field pass to payload will be ignore by TaskSerializer. if I were you I would check the dict data making an intersecction with the fields of your TaskSerializer. then validate if there is an data that is not normal and raise an error.

Comment: Why do you want to return errors for fields which will not impact the model, because they were already removed/trimmed from data passed to serializer?
Your expectation is little awkward, which normally web apis don't do.

Comment: @AkshayPratapSingh I think I got it now, I was missing the trimmed/removed part of a data when passed to Serializer. Thanks